# Is it frowned upon to edit questions partially to create certain homepage arrangements?

Tags: discussion, editing

For example, making not-particularly-important grammar tweaks to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31385/why-couldnt-red-pills-be-used-instead-of-running-towards-a-ringing-telephone) in order to make the homepage, briefly, have questions concerning red, white and blue at the top?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that you're taking your life into your hands with this one. As long as the edits are *genuinely* improving the questions, you're free and clear. The fact that they happen to spell out a word is really neither here nor there.

If, on the other hand your edits are frivolous (which may be something of a temptation if you're trying to get that last letter into place before someone mucks it up) then I would be minded to offer a warning or even consider a small suspension given that you've abused your privileges as a high rep user.

Note also that using the edit queue to spell out a **rude word** would be viewed very poorly.

Answer (score -1):

Challenge accepted and accomplished:

[image: My Handle is the first letter of the top questions]

Comment: Come on Downvoters- what's wrong with a bit of fun?  It's not as though it negatively impacted the questions or site!